# Laravel database queues not firing at all

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan, job-scheduling

We use multiple queues (SQS, redis and database).
We use Laravel Vapor that allows a maximum processing time of 15 minutes, so smaller jobs are executed there and it works.

So to process longer queues, I created an EC2 instance using the same codebase, connected to the common RDS instance, it all works.
I can also see that there are jobs pending in the `jobs` table using tinker in the EC2 instance.
Now here's the problem:

Running `php artisan queue:work database --queue=queueName` is not working at all!
It just keeps on listening for any activity even when there are entries in the `jobs` table.

How do I know that the code is working?
Because I used the remote DB credentials in the local development .env and fired the same command and it processed the queue.

I've tried deleting and reinstalling composer packages but none of it works.

Comment: So do you end up getting Failed Jobs or don't you get it either?

Comment: No, the jobs table doesn't get affected at all, the reserved_at is null, attempts value is 0, the console doesn't even say that it's processing the queued job, it's just empty.

Comment: how are you queueing the jobs? Make sure you use both database as the connection and the correct queue name.

Comment: Yes, there's no issue with that, I've made sure the connection value is database and while running the artisan command I also mentioned the connection in arguments.

Comment: For queued jobs you need to specify connection, but also queue name. Make sure both are the correct values e.g. based on your example you'd do `MyJob::dispatch()->onConnection('database')->onQueue('queueName')`

Comment: Always run php artisan queue:restart before queue:work. Reason being laravel caches the job code so you need to clear the cache.